# Getting a } error when setting onclicklistener

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to set an onclicklistener for an imagebutton in eclipse. When clicked, the app should lead to the default contacts app. This is the code I have but I'm getting an error with the "}" brackets and I can't seem to figure out whats the problem. Can anyone help?

```
public class First extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        addButtonListener();
    }

    private void addButtonListener() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //finding your image button
        ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);  
               startActivityForResult(intent, 1); 

            }); //!!!!THE ERROR APPEARS UNDER THE } BRACKET ON THIS LINE!!!
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
            //Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first, menu);
        return true;
     }
}
```

Comment: You opened { twicw but closed only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple Syntax Error. You have misplaced the end-parenthesis. Also, you have declared a method inside a method. The below code-block should be outside the method.

The correct should be:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    //Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first, menu);
    return true;
}

private void addButtonListener() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //finding your image button
    ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);  
           startActivityForResult(intent, 1); 

        } // `);` moved from here to the line below
    });
} // This little thingy was waaaaaay too far down. This is the end for one method

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){ // So here another method can start
    //Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! I'm new to this and I've been trying to sort that out since last night!...just one thing now..the contact list comes up but when selected it just goes back to my app..so I guess i have to do some research and look into onActivityResult now

Comment: @user2490199 Yes, do some research on your own first and then later if you absolutely haven't found a solution, post a **new** question here and show **solutions that you have tried**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void addButtonListener() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //finding your image button
    ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);  
           startActivityForResult(intent, 1); 
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
private void addButtonListener() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

//finding your image button
ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);  
       startActivityForResult(intent, 1); 

        }); //!!!!THE ERROR APPEARS UNDER THE } BRACKET ON THIS LINE!!!
}
```

To this:

```
private void addButtonListener() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //finding your image button
    ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);  
           startActivityForResult(intent, 1); 
        }
    }); //!!!!THE ERROR APPEARS UNDER THE } BRACKET ON THIS LINE!!!
}
```